# In Java, how do I efficiently trim 0's from the start and the end of a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, trim

For reasons outside my control, I need to parse a huge file that has an universe of empty bytes at the beginning and the end of the file, and a very small portion that is actually valid (5 KBs at most). This is the code I came up with:

```
@NonNull
public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(@NonNull File file, boolean bTrimNulls) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        if (fis.read(buffer) == -1) {
            throw new IOException("EOF reached while trying to read the whole file");
        }
    } finally {
        closeSafely(fis);
    }
    if (!bTrimNulls) {
        return buffer;
    }
    int nFirstValidByteIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] != 0) {
            nFirstValidByteIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    int nLastValidByteIndex = 0;
    for (int i = buffer.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (buffer[i] != 0) {
            nLastValidByteIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return copyBufferRange(buffer, nFirstValidByteIndex, nLastValidByteIndex + 1);
}
```

Is there any better alternative to this?

EDIT: The valid bytes in the buffer correspond to an XML file.

Comment: Might there be empty bytes in the middle of the file? I mean, after you hit the first non-zero byte and before you reach the last non-zero byte, can zero bytes appear?

Comment: Yes, there might be.

Comment: How big is very big?  Is it guaranteed that there will be no more than 5kb of data?

Comment: One thing you could do is not copy the whole file into memory, but filter out the buffers (at least at the start, end might be tricky, I suppose you can do that, too if you know the payload is only 5k at most) while you are reading them.

Comment: Does `fis.read` (without a loop) reliably work like that? Isn't it free to stop copying at any time?

Comment: Yes, it is quite fast. Someone below mentioned using Files.readAllBytes() which I suppose will do a better job than my code. BTW, the valid bytes in the buffer correspond to an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is rather efficient. In fact, you are looking from both ends of the array the indexes of the first 1's and then create a subarray of data.

Why do you feel you need to improve your algorithm?

Careful: **premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming**, [quote by Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Because the code is actually quite slow, and this is code for an application framework, rather than an actual app, so perfomance is a must. Also I don't really like that quote from Donald Knuth. A lot of times, the best time to optimize is when designing the algorithm, not later, even if I think that I should never sacrifice code readability unless it's essential.

Comment: Are you sure the slow part is the trimming of the array? Not reading in the whole file into memory?

Comment: Trimming is not the slow part, finding the first and the last indexes is. I am going to try searching with bigger chunks instead of one by one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a time complexity of n, which can be too much for large files as you said. Fortunately we know that the non-zero part has a maximum size m, so we can search the file in steps of m. If we miss (hit a zero in the middle of the payload), we need to repeat it until we found it. So the complexity goes to around n/m if the probability of a zero in the payload is sufficiently low.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

class Test
{

    public static int findNonZero(byte[] sparse, int max)
    {
        // looks quadratic but isn't in practice if the probability of zero in the payload is low, i.e. 1/256 for random values
        for(int offset=0;offset<max;offset++)
        {
            for(int i=0;(i+offset)<sparse.length; i+=max)
            {
                if(sparse[i+offset]!=0)
                {
                    return i+offset;                    
                }
            }
        }
         // in production code you could handle this differently but this is just an example
        throw new RuntimeException("Nonzero value not found");
    }

    public static byte[] trim(byte[] sparse, int max)
    {
        int index = findNonZero(sparse, max);
        // go to the left and go to the right until you find (max) zeroes
        int from = ...
        int to = ...
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(sparse, from, to);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create test data
        int size = 5000;
        byte[] test = new byte[1_000_000_000];
        byte[] payload = new byte[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        r.nextBytes(payload);
        payload[0]=(byte)(r.nextInt(Byte.MAX_VALUE-1)+1); // ensure start isnt zero
        payload[payload.length-1]=(byte)(r.nextInt(Byte.MAX_VALUE-1)+1);  // ensure end isnt zero
        System.arraycopy(payload, 0, test, r.nextInt(test.length-size), size);

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(payload,trim(test,size)));
    }
}
```

I left the last part for you, where you need to go to the left and go to the right until you find (max) zeroes and determine from and to indices.

You could further improve the real-world performance by setting subsequent offsets further apart, for example offset_1 = 0, offset_2 = max/2, offset_3 = 1/4 max, offset_4 = 3/4 max and so on.

Comment: @Thilo: I wasn't finished writing. I added the differences now. It actually isn't really binary search you are right I will revise it.

Comment: Time-complexity cannot really drop below O(n) if we also have to read a file of size n.

Comment: @Thilo: That is correct. However you can also access random portions of files on many types of storage devices and rewrite the code to seek at certain parts of the file directly. Whether that is more efficient depends on the particular values for n and m and on the device. However I found this problem also interesting from a theoretical standpoint where you can assume the array is already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. For really large files one would use a limited buffer, a FileChannel,
a SeekableByteChannel with a ByteBuffer.

Just the code could be a bit nicer. A parameter `Path` instead of `File` would be more general and more modern.

```
public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(@NonNull File file, boolean trimNulls)
        throws IOException {
    Path path = file.toPath();
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    if (trimNulls) {
        int start = 0;
        while (start < content.length && content[start] == 0) {
            ++start;
        }
        int end = content.length;
        while (end > start && content[end - 1] == 0) {
            --end;
        }
        content = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, start, end);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: I have used File since this is going to run in Android, and Files.readAllBytes() only exist in Android >= 8.X.X. I will use it on newer versions because it probably does a better job than FileInputStream + buffer. Thanks!